# ROS Answers SE migration: ros2 turtlesim

Tags: simulation, ros2, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wonder whether there will be soon a package for turtlesim on ROS2.
I downloaded bouncy, but there is no turtlesim package.
Also, is there any robot simulator in current ROS2 packages?
When it will be released?

Thanks

Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298907/ros2-turtlesim/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2018-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no plan to port [turtlesim](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/melodic-devel/turtlesim). Our engineering time is focused on implementing additional features and migrate packages which are requested most to be used for applications. If anybody would like to work on porting `turtlesim` please feel free to create a pull request for it. I am happy to review it.

For the next ROS 2 release Crystal scheduled for Dec. 2018 we are working on porting `gazebo_ros_pkgs` as well as some of the plugins. That will provide native integration with ROS 2. Until then you can use Gazebo with the ROS 1 integration together with the [ros1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1